# How to print full stack trace of an Error?

Tags: julia

`println` not printing stack trace, this code

```
try
  eval(Meta.parse("invalidfn()"))
catch error
  println(error)
end
```

produces

```
UndefVarError(:invalidfn)
```

And `error.msg` or `fieldnames(error)` are not working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`catch_backtrace`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/stacktraces/#Error-handling-1), together with the `@error` macro from the [`Logging` standard library](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Logging/):

```
julia> try
         eval(Meta.parse("invalidfn()"))
       catch e
         @error "Something went wrong" exception=(e, catch_backtrace())
       end
┌ Error: Something went wrong
│   exception =
│    UndefVarError: invalidfn not defined
│    Stacktrace:
│     [1] top-level scope at REPL[1]:1
│     [2] eval at ./boot.jl:330 [inlined]
│     [3] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:425
│     [4] top-level scope at REPL[1]:2
│     [5] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:330
│     [6] eval_user_input(::Any, ::REPL.REPLBackend) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/REPL/src/REPL.jl:86
│     [7] macro expansion at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/REPL/src/REPL.jl:118 [inlined]
│     [8] (::REPL.var"#26#27"{REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./task.jl:333
└ @ Main REPL[1]:4
```

As an alternative, you can directly call the (undocumented) three-argument [`showerror`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.showerror):

```
julia> try
         eval(Meta.parse("invalidfn()"))
       catch e
         showerror(stdout, e, catch_backtrace())
       end
UndefVarError: invalidfn not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[1]:1
 [2] eval at ./boot.jl:330 [inlined]
 [3] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:425
 [4] top-level scope at REPL[1]:2
 [5] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:330
 [6] eval_user_input(::Any, ::REPL.REPLBackend) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/REPL/src/REPL.jl:86
 [7] macro expansion at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/REPL/src/REPL.jl:118 [inlined]
 [8] (::REPL.var"#26#27"{REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./task.jl:333
```

Comment: @giordano thanks, but it looks different from how the default error looks in the console, is there a way to print it in the same format?

Comment: if you `throw(e)` in a catch I think that is the same as just "doing the normal thing".

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I can't `throw` it, there's infinite `while` loop that would be exited if I throw an exception from it.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin Have a look at the updated answer, the three-argument `showerror` should be what you're looking for.

Comment: @giordano I haven't noticed it thanks, yes it works as expected.